# Please explain this MDN example

Tags: javascript, function, keydown

I'm learning javascript through MDN documentation. They have an example on the [function topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions) which apparently I'm unable to understand.

```
const textBox = document.querySelector("#textBox");

const output = document.querySelector("#output");

textBox.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => output.textContent = `You pressed "${event.key}".`);
```

I've read a few documentation on**key down** function and I assume it is supposed to return some value for every character entered (correct me if I'm wrong); but in the example on MDN, it only returns **enter** when I press enter key and **backspace** when I press backspace (while input box has no other characters). I'm reading this example on a mobile device btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost right about the `keydown` event. It's supposed to call the callBack function with each keydown press when the input HTML element is activated or it is able receive the event (the HTML element with the `#textBox` id). It means that if the `#textBox` element is not selected/activated, it will not listen to any 'keydown' event, and as a result it will not call the callBack function: `(event) => output.textContent = You pressed "${event.key}".`

`keydown` is an event which is listened by the `#textBox` element via `addEventListener()` method. To be more clear, the `addEventListener()` method sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target. The target in this case is the html element with the `#textBox` id.

In short the code you wrote will add the `keydown` event to the input element, and call the `(event) => output.textContent = You pressed "${event.key}".` function when the event is happening.

You can read more about [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on MDN.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working, as long as you add the proper html.

```js
const textBox = document.querySelector("#textBox");

const output = document.querySelector("#output");

textBox.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => output.textContent = `You pressed "${event.key}".`);
```

```html
<input id="textBox">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: On my device, it returns **Unidentified** for every character other than enter and backspace.

Comment: `event.key` is new, but not *that* new. maybe try `event.keyCode` see if you get the key code

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks! (Gotta read some documentation)